# configure proxy credential for Git Bash, but facing special character issue

Tags: git, proxy, special-characters

wanted to set  proxy credential for Git Bash, 
but my password contain special character at the end, example my password is 1122!!@@

i tried 
proxy = http://username:1122!!@@@proxy.com:8xxx
and also proxy = http://username:1122%21%21%40%40@proxy.com:8xxx also cant work.

rather than change password, how could i text it able the .gitconfig to read it?

Comment: `git config --global http.proxy "http://username:1122%21%21%40%40@proxy.com:8xxx"`

Answer (score 0):

The second form (which is [percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters)) should work.

The correct setting is **[`http.proxy`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpproxy)**, as commented.

The alternative is, for testing, to set **environment variables** in your git bash session:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://username:1122%21%21%40%40@proxy.com:8xxx
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:1122%21%21%40%40@proxy.com:8xxx
```

And remove any proxy entry from your git config: `git config -l|grep -i proxy`

If that works, you can add those `export` directives in your `~/.bashrc`.